# XCode 5.1.1 freezes when running app on device, works on simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

When I'm trying to run my app on simulator, everything works as expected.

However, when I run on a device (iPhone 5S):

1. The app icon appears on device (and I can open the app manually), but XCode won't launch the app as normally.
2. XCode shows "Running [appName] on iPhone".
3. Console is empty, no any messages at all.
4. XCode freezes, the *beachball* appears and MacBook gets really slow and unresponsive. The only way to recover from this is to force shutdown and restart my computer.

XCode version is 5.1.1 and OS X 10.9.4. My iPhone 5S has iOS 7.1.2 and I've set Base SDK as "Latest iOs (iOs 7.1)" in XCode Build Settings.

Do you have any idea what could cause this? I already tried reinstalling XCode and checking out my project from svn to another path.

Comment: Does unplugging the device also resolves the freezing / pizza of death?

Comment: If I unplug my device, XCode still shows "Running [appName] on iPhone" and is freezed

Comment: Maybe it's the cable ? Did you tried with another one ? And did you try with another device ?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the phone?

Comment: Rebooting the phone, trying another cable, or testing with another USB port won't help. This is the only device I can test on for now.

Comment: I'm not sure you have a problem with _Xcode_, you might have a problem with your own application instead... huhh?

Comment: @holex: I wasn't able to install any sample projects to my device, so it wasn't a problem with my app. Check my own answer below, it solved the issue! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by closing XCode and executing these commands in terminal:

```
rm -rf $HOME/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode
rm -rf $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.*
rm -rf $HOME/Library/Saved\ Application\ State/com.apple.dt.Xcode.savedState
rm -rf $HOME/Library/Developer/Xcode
```

Source: http://ioslau.blogspot.fi/2013/08/resetting-xcode-settingspreferences.html

I don't still know what the problem actually was, but apparently there was something wrong in the XCode preferences and removing+reinstalling XCode will still leave some settings-files in the system. But now it works like a charm!

Comment: I've tried this before myself, but users should be aware that these commands will delete some important things, like Xcode preferences, your archived app builds, and I believe debug symbols for particular iOS versions. So, know the consequences, or have these backed up first.

Answer (score 0):

When restarting/reinstalling Xcode does not assist with a problem of XCode hanging when building and running on an iOS device, You should reboot the iOS device.

Comment: I've tried rebooting the device, but the problem persists

Comment: Are you using a special SDK, API, or Loader ?

Comment: Also, do you have another version of the app on your iPhone with a different provisioning profile ?

Comment: No special stuff and I don't have another version installed

Comment: are you using #ifdef DEBUG anywhere ?

Comment: DOes your iphone have enough space for the application and the content it creates if any ?

Comment: Yes, there's 13 GB available. And the app is actually installed on the device, but it just won't launch automatically (no console connection and XCode freezes). I tested now with some simple sample projects (other than my project) and with those it's the same result :/

Comment: Did you do clean and clean build ?

Comment: I really suspect your device...

Comment: Yes I also suspect your device and reccomend that you go to Settings > General > Reset > Reset All Settings and reboot your iphone once more

Comment: @Zigglzworth: I tried now resetting all settings on the device as you said, but that didn't help either

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas :(

Comment: Thanks for your efforts anyways! :)